# Fail to run the STOP function for a running imported file

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-import

**In my main code, I imported the posted HX711 module which looks like:**

```
   #! /usr/bin/python2

   import time
   import sys

   EMULATE_HX711=False



   if not EMULATE_HX711:
       import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
       from hx711 import HX711
   else:
       from emulated_hx711 import HX711

   def cleanAndExit():
       print("Cleaning...")

       if not EMULATE_HX711:
           GPIO.cleanup()
        
       print("Bye!")
       sys.exit()

   hx = HX711(5, 6)

   hx.set_reading_format("MSB", "MSB")


   #---Actual Calibrated Weight and display value---#
   #referenceUnit = display value/actual weight -> Temporarily =1 until first calibration with load 
   cells
   referenceUnit = 1
   hx.set_reference_unit(referenceUnit)

   hx.reset()

   hx.tare()

   print("Tare done! Add weight now...")


   while True:
       try:
           # np_arr8_string = hx.get_np_arr8_string()
           # binary_string = hx.get_binary_string()
           # print binary_string + " " + np_arr8_string
        
           val = hx.get_weight(5)
           print(val)

           # To get weight from both channels (if you have load cells hooked up 
           # to both channel A and B), do something like this
           #val_A = hx.get_weight_A(5)
           #val_B = hx.get_weight_B(5)
           #print "A: %s  B: %s" % ( val_A, val_B )

           hx.power_down()
           hx.power_up()
           time.sleep(0.1)

       except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
           cleanAndExit()
```

**This module's GITHUB link is here: https://github.com/tatobari/hx711py. So in a new file I tried to import the "example.py" file and run it. It runs. But when I import the cleanAndExit() function using from example import cleanAndExit(). The system doesn't seem to stop. My code looks like this:**

```
import time
from time import sleep
import example
from example import cleanAndExit
for i in range(5):
   sleep.time(5)
cleanAndExit()
```

Despite the function being called, it didn't work and didn't stop the program. After running the code, I was expect a stop in the command line. Instead, despite throwing no errors, the module seems to continue running and outputting data. I was expecting a clean stop, which is similar to what Ctrl C would do since the sys.exit() was mentioned in the cleanAndExit() function.

I'm new to Python. Can anyone help me?

Comment: the imported HX711 module name was "example.py"

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the behavior you are looking for?  Are you expecting the `cleanAndExit` function to interrupt the `sleep`s above?

Comment: Mb I was trying to just stop the program but the cleanAndExit() didn't work, which was called in the imported "example.py". The sleep I put in just to run the imported file for 5s then use the function to stop it

Comment: _The function didn't work_ This is too vague.  What exactly do you mean by "didn't work"?  Did you get an exception?  Did you expect to see some specific behavior which didn't occur?

Comment: Ah sr for the confusion. After running the code, I was expect a stop in the command line. Instead, despite throwing no errors, the module seems to continue running and outputting data. I was expecting a clean stop, which is similar to what Ctrl C would do since the sys.exit() was mentioned in the cleanAndExit() function

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. This is because by importing the module "example.py", the shell runs the entire code automatically. So while the module is running, it blocks any further command from the shell since it's constantly outputting readings due to being "busy". Therefore, using if **name**='**main**': I can separate the data reading part underneath this within another function like main() to allow this to be run with the file being imported and let the cleanAndExit() function only execute upon being called. So now the code in the example.py file will be something like:

```
def cleanAndExit():
   ... #same code

def main():
   hx = HX711(5,6)
   ...#all the automatically run actions when being imported

if __name__ = '__main__':
  main() #only run this function while other not mentioned function can only be 
         #executed when specifically called
```